# Force rsyslogd to create new file before somebody will write to it

Tags: rsyslog

I'm using rsyslogd 7.4.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I've updated the configuration file */etc/rsyslog.d/30-component.conf* with the following content:

```
# provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$EscapeControlCharactersOnReceive off

$outchannel network,/var/log/component/network.log,10240000,/usr/home/component/bin/./rotate.sh /var/log/component/network.log

if $programname == 'Network' then :omfile:$network
if $programname == 'Network' then stop

if $programname == 'Network' then /var/log/gwc/network.log
```

From time to time I need to delete the *network.log* file manually. After that, I'm always having to restart the daemon. The problem is that the new file will not be created until somebody will write to appropriate syslog channel ('Network' in my case). But I want to have *network.log* file even if it will be empty.

Some time ago, I used rsyslogd 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 10.04 with nearly the same configuration. The only difference is that "**~**" was replaced with "**stop**" and "**:omfile:**" was introduced. With that version everything was fine and the new file was created after the daemon was restarted.

I suppose that with rsyslogd 4.2.0 next line leads to file new creation:

```
if $programname == 'Network' then /var/log/gwc/network.log
```

But it seems it doesn't work with 7.4.4. How I can achieve this old version behavior with the newer version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rsyslog 5.x+ does not create a file (or open a network connection) until it has a log entry that matches that filter.

This is a change from earlier behaviour related to fixing problems with dropping privileges. There isn't currently (as of 8.5) a way to force file creation of an empty file.

Answer (score -1):

Forcing log rotation is usually done with logrotate too. For example, rhel like distros have the log rotation config in /etc/logrotate.d/.

For example: /etc/logrotate.d/syslog contains the rules for rsyslogd files.In this case, I can force log rotation using :

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/syslog
```

Answer (score -1):

```
logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.conf
```